# Next-Auth Redirect Sign Out

Tags: next.js, next-auth

How can I redirect my logout to the URL I have in my .env ?

This is my .env.local

NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://www.instagram.com.ar/

This is my sidebar.tsx

```
<a
onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL })}
className="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg  hover:bg-red-100  group cursor-pointer">
<FiLogOut size={25} />
<span className="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Cerrar Sesión</span>
</a>
```

This is my route.ts in api/[nextauth]

```
`const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "email", placeholder: "test@test.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const res = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/auth/login`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: credentials?.email,
              password: credentials?.password,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        );
        const user = await res.json();
        if (user.error) throw user;

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token as any;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };`
```

I tried with `onClick={() =>signOut({ callbackUrl: 'www.instagram.com.ar' })}` and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by modifying the callbacks object in [...nextauth.ts] file like this:**

```
   callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
    // Allows relative callback URLs
    if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
    // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
    else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
    return baseUrl
  }
}
```

in your case you can add a condition like this in the callback :

```
  callbacks: {
  async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {

    // Handle logout redirect
    if (url.startsWith("/logout")) return "https://www.instagram.com.ar/";

    // Allows relative callback URLs
    if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
    
    // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
    else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
    
    // Default to the base URL
    return baseUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying that but it keeps redirecting me to localhost:3000